# How to symlink alias and function dotfiles

Tags: bash, alias, symlink, dotfiles

I trying to make my own alises. I have this in my `~/dotfiles`:

```sh
alias hello="echo Hello"
```

I try to symlink this:

```
ln -sn "~/dotfiles/.alias" ~
```

But after this when i run my alias nothing happens
Is there a path for aliases in home to symlink it?

Comment: What makes you think that a `~/.alias` file has a special role in `bash`? And it is `alias hello="echo Hello"`, not `alias hello = "echo Hello"` (no spaces around the `=` sign).

Comment: No, I meant that for example ~/.vimrc is config file for vim and we can make a symlink for it. But how we could make symlink for this kind of things(aliases

Comment: Then you must use a standard `bash` configuration file (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`...) Read the documentation (`man bash`) to understand the differences between them and when they are sourced by `bash`. Once you will have chosen one of them, add to it a source command for your alias file: `source ~/dotfiles/.alias`. Note that aliases are a bit outdated and not really recommended any more. Prefer `bash` functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are sourcing your aliases file in your .bashrc or .zshrc

the code for that in your .bashrc or .zshrc should look something like this:

```
if [ -f ~/dotfiles/.aliases ];
then source ~/dotfiles/.aliases
fi
```